# How to use GridSearchCV , cross_val_score and a model

Tags: python, gridsearchcv

I need to find best hyperparams for ANN and then run prediction on the best model. I use `KerasRegressor`. I find conflicting examples and advices. Please help me understand the right sequence and which params to use when.

1. I split my data into **Train** and **Test** datasets
2. I look for the best hyperparams using `GridSearchCV` on **Train** dataset
   `GridSearchCV.fit(X_Train, Y_Train)`
3. I take `GridSearchCV.best_estimator_` and use it in `cross_val_score` on **Test** dataset, i.e
   `cross_val_score(model.best_estimator_, X_Test, Y_Test , scoring='r2')`

   - *I'm not sure if I need to do this step? In theory, it should show similar r2 scores as GridSearchCV did for this best_estimator_ shouldn't it* ?
4. I use `model.best_estimator_.predict( X_Test, Y_Test)` on Test data to predict the results.    I.e I pass **best_estimator_** from `GridSearchCV` to run actual **prediction**.

   - *Is this correct* ?
     *Do I need to **fit** again `model.best_estimator_` on Train data before doing a prediction? Or does it keep all the weights found during `GridSearchCV` ?
     *Do I need to save weights to be able to reuse it later* ?

Comment: you cannot use the test set to select the best parameters and tune your model. that's the job of the validation dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you use `GridSearchCV` on your training set, you will have an object which contains the best trained model with the best parameters.

```
gs = GridSearchCV.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

This is also evident from running `gs.best_params_` which will print out the best parameters of the model after cross validation. Now, you can make predictions on your test set directly by running `gs.predict(X_test, y_test)` which will use the best selected model to predict on your test set.

For question 3, you don't need to use `cross_val_score` again, as this is an helper function that allows you to perform cross validation on your dataset and returns the score of each `fold` of the data split.

For question 4, I believe this answer is quite explanatory: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/26535

Comment: Thanks a lot Olasimbo! All makes perfect sense.